# issue run nerdctl inside docker container: failed to create shim task: failed to mount rootfs component: invalid argument: unknown

Tags: docker, mount, containerd, rootfs, nerdctl

### solution to this exact problem is commented below.

original problem:
when try to buildup a docker container and using nerdctl inside it, an error occurs:

```
failed to create shim task: failed to mount rootfs component: invalid argument: unknown.
```

So, main question is; how to work this out???
I see containerd/runtime/v2/manager.go, but no idea of why cause rootfs component mount err.
[image]

To reproduce the issue:
clone nerdctl & compile it using:

```
cd ${dir_of_nerdctl} && make all
```

maintain a dockerfile at the same dir level of nerdctl like:

```
FROM alpine:3.18

# ENV http_proxy='http://xxxx:8080'
# ENV https_proxy='http://xxxx:8080'

RUN apk update && \
    apk add --no-cache vim && \
    apk add --no-cache make && \
    apk add --no-cache go && \
    apk add --no-cache git && \
    apk add --no-cache containerd && \
    apk add --no-cache openrc && \
    apk add --no-cache cni-plugins && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

VOLUME [ "/sys/fs/cgroup" ]

COPY ./s0_entry.sh /scripts/s0_entry.sh
     
ENTRYPOINT ["/scripts/s0_entry.sh"]
```

s0_entry.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

. /scripts/logger.sh

prepare_nerdctl_binary() {
    nerdctl='/nerdctl/_output/nerdctl'
    if [ -f "${nerdctl}" ]; then
        ln -s "${nerdctl}" /usr/local/bin/nerdctl
        echo 'nerdctl binary add to path'
    else
        echo 'no binary executable nerdctl found under /nerdctl/_outputs'
        exit 1
    fi
}

startup_containerd_openrc() {
    # init
    rc-status
    touch /run/openrc/softlevel
    # config
    rc-update add containerd default
    # start
    rc-service containerd start
    rc-service containerd status
    echo 'containerd started'
}

start() {
    nerdctl ps -a
    echo 'nerdctl started'
}

echo "$0 running"

prepare_nerdctl_binary
startup_containerd_openrc

echo "$0 finsihed"

exec "$@"
```

cmd to buildup docker image:

```
docker build -t nerdctl:test .
```

cmd to enter alpine container:

```
scriptpath="$( cd -- "$(dirname "$0")" >/dev/null 2>&1 ; pwd -P )"
docker run -it --rm -v "$scriptpath"/nerdctl:/nerdctl --privileged --cap-add all nerdctl:test sh
```

try startup another alpine container with nerdctl inside:

```
nerdctl run -it --rm alpine:latest sh
```

the error like the title claim occur.

Comment: the issue is solved by asking the containerd community for help. for a brief guide here:
the vol for cgroup is not needed, while need to mount a vol (ext4, xfs) into container /var/lib/containerd.
see: https://github.com/containerd/containerd/discussions/9667